# ModelConfiguration does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to get a template working that will correctly rename my navigation properties in the entity framework. Here are first five lines of the template:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
<#@ assembly name="System.Text.RegularExpressions"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers" #>
```

However when I try to "Run the Custom Tool" I get the following error:

> Error      Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'ModelConfiguration' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)     c:\Users\Clay\AppData\Local\Temp\05ugyat2.0.cs  21

The solution has EntityFramework 6.1.3 installed as a NuGet package.
However I (strangely) also had to add a reference to System.Data.Entity (V4.0.0.0) to the project. My understanding from reading comments in other similar SO questions is that you should only need to add the reference if the package isn't part of your solution.
When I added the reference it I could see System.Data.Entity in the Object Browser.

I added the assembly into the project's Web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Still getting the error! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is just a mess up of different packages. I suggest removing EF through nuget, remove any remaining dll's related to EF, remove your bin folder (just to be sure) and reinstall EF. Don't combine using nuget and adding libraries manually, it's asking for trouble

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @AlexanderDerck. I tried it and unfortunately the problem still persists. I would have surprised if this had been the solution though, as this was the first project in a totally fresh install of Visual Studio 2015. Now I'm down to my last option: Uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio, but I fear it won't make a difference.

Comment: Uninstalled & reinstalled Visual Studio - no difference.